# jQuery cycle photos in div background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've accomplish successfully when the mouse overs a `div` to cycle and change the `background-image` **and stop the other** `divs` **from cycle**.

What happens is that, this `div` have a title which appears when the mouse is hovering the `div`, and if I grab the cursor and put it over the title and then move the cursor again to the other `div` title, the cycle continues in both `divs`, and I would like not to.

I'm clearing the `interval cycle` this way: `clearInterval(theInterval);`

But, somehow, **when the title is being hovered** it doesn't stop the others cycle.

The problem can be seen in **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9eLoau3/1/)**.

**Simulate the problem:**

1. Put your cursor over the title
2. Move your cursor quickly to the other div title
3. You'll see that both divs continue the cycle independently (and I want only one to cycle)

**Simulate how it works:**

1. Put your cursor over the div (without being in the title)
2. Move your cursor to the other div
3. You'll see that only one div cycles

Comment: Replace 'mouseover' with 'mouseenter' and 'mouseout' with 'mouseleave'. The code will also simplify - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9d16b2L/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a problem with the nature of the `mouseover` event, and the divs being in such close proximity. Try using the hover event instead. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohoqjfL/)

In essence:

```
$('.collection-photo').hover(function(){
  // mouse over stuff here
}, function() {
  // mouse out stuff here
});
```

Comment: Right solution, wrong analysis. `.hover()` works because it is equivalent to `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut )`;

Comment: So you're saying `hover()`, which is `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, behaves different than `mouseover`? Is that not what I said - that the nature of it is different?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. It's the "divs being in such close proximity" that I disagree with. I don't think that's relevant. It's to do with `mouseleave` being more reliable than `mouseout`.

Comment: If you take his original example and add a 20px bottom margin to it, I can't reproduce the error. But I see what you're saying, fair enough.

Comment: The crux of the issue is where the mouse leaves. In the original fiddle plus your bottom margin, try leaving from the "Just testing" overlay. For me, in Opera, even with a substantial margin, the effect is manifest though interestingly if I pass through the margin slowly, it tends not to happen. Leaving from the uncovered image, the effect happens only very occasionally.